# Is it possible to get all column names with data types from PgSQL database using SQLAlchemy automap?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get column names and data types from PgSQL database. The result should look like an output from this query:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

I tried to get this information using `automap_base()` and `inspect()`. Unfortunately, `automap_base()` don't map any schema tables, and `inspect` object has no methods that gives column names and data types.
I also tried `column_descriptions` method this way:

```
In [1]:
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, inspect


Base = automap_base()

db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'password'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_name = 'db_test'

engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/{database_name}'.format(
        user=db_user,
        password=db_password,
        hostname='{}:{}'.format(db_host, '5432'),
        database_name=db_name
    )
)

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
clients = Base.classes.clients
session = Session(engine)

q = session.query(clients)
q.column_descriptions
```

```
Out [1]:

[{'name': 'clients',
  'type': sqlalchemy.ext.automap.clients,
  'aliased': False,
  'expr': sqlalchemy.ext.automap.clients,
  'entity': sqlalchemy.ext.automap.clients}]
```

Is there a way to get column names and data types of table from existing database, using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple:

```
meta = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)

meta.sorted_tables
```

`reflect()` method takes metadata from existing database and stores it in `MetaData` object, `sorted_tables` method shows all tables, columns and datatypes stored in `MetaData`